# Way to redefine a macro constant in just one single line using C syntax?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to redefine the value of a macro constant on a certain condition in my C source code. I don´t be able to use conditional preprocessing directives for defining `LEN_OSG` because whether it is redefined with a another value or not is decided at run-time.

What I already have is:

```
if(condition)                      // proof condition for replacing the value in LEN_OSG.
{
   if(LEN_OSG != CBS_LEN)          // check if LEN_OS already has the value in CBS_LEN.
   {
      #undef LEN_OSG               // undefine macro LEN_OSG by using `#undef` directive.
      #define LEN_OSG CBS_LEN      // recreate the macro LEN_OSG with new value.
   }
}
```

Does the C syntax allow another way to abbreviate this instead of to using the `#undef` directive and thereafter recreating the macro with a new value by another `#define` directive (in just a single line)?

---

Desired solution would be something like that:

```
if(LEN_OSG != CBS_LEN)          // check if LEN_OS already has the value in CBS_LEN.
{
   #redefine LEN_OSG CBS_LEN    // redefine LEN_OS with another value in one line. 
}
```

Comment: No. All preprocessor directives (`#define`, `#if`, ...) have disappeared when the compiler itself starts to run.

Comment: You are mixing compile-time and run-time stuff here. Your `if`s are evaluated at run-time by your program and the target's processor, but the preprocessor lines are evaluated at compile-time by the compiler and the host's processor. -- What do you really want to achieve? Please show us a [example].

Comment: It's impossible to redefine a macro at runtime. C scopes do not affect preprocessor directives.

Comment: @pmg: Preprocessing is integrated into GCC and Clang, so the preprocessing directives are certainly still present when the compiler starts, unless a user explicitly requests a separate preprocessing execution. It is even possible to get phase 7 (semantic analysis) error messages from code containing an `#error` directive, thus proving that some traditional compilation is performed before phase 4 (preprocessing) is complete.

Comment: @thebusybee Idiotic mistake from me. I edited the question, but my issue still remains - I´m asking for a way to abbreviate the redefining of a macro without using `#undef` and `#define`.

Comment: Well, there is none. Why do you need a one-liner?

Comment: Your edit has fundamentally changed the question to the point that both existing answers (admittedly one of them mine) have been invalidated. Please do not edit like that. If this answered question is not really what you wanted to ask, then please create a new question. For that please elaborate on WHY you want a one-line solution. Also have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I get the impression that you might benefit from the ideas outlined there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to mix runtime code execution with preprocessor directives, i.e. things which have an effect even before compiling.
That does not work.

Comment: Yes, that was mistake. I apoligize for being so idiotic. I´ve edited the question, so that my intention comes clear and valid.

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not work as you expect. `#define` is executed at compile time, so you must use compile-time `#if` with it. Otherwise it is always executed.

Also, there is no `#redefine`, so two commands are needed.

If you have a runtime condition, use a normal variable and change its value during runtime.

Comment: Yes, I didn´t compiled it before - sorry for being dumb - but the case I´m asking for still remains. I´ve edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio See my answer: "Also, there is no #redefine, so two commands are needed."